# rails geocoder find nearby locations from current_loation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I have just followed the RailsCast tutorial for geocoder
http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder. I am using Rails 4.

In the gem documentation it states that Geocoder can also be geocoded by IP address. such as inside the location model

`geocoded_by :full_street_address   # can also be an IP address`

at the moment my app finds latitude and longitudes as floats and using address field in a location model which is defined like:

```
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
```

controller is standard scaffolding nothing changed so it does the standard CRUD of locations.

and in the location/show view(you will notice i am already starting to mess around with request.location but need to view locations based on nearby locations from the current location (ip_address)):

```
 <p>
 <strong>Address:</strong>
 <%= @location.address %>
 </p>

 <p>

<h3>Nearby Locations</h3>
<ul>

<%= request.location %> #bring back something like #<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x007fb15ae25c80>
<%= request.location.latitude %> # brings back latitude etc 


<% for location in @location.nearbys(10) %>
<li> <%= link_to location.address, location %> (<%= location.distance.round(2)%> miles)</li>
<% end %>
```

Now I know I cant see coordinates for lat and long if i'm on development mode so these only work on production mode. However, if I want to search using nearby locations using current location or IP instead of nearbys based on address. How would I do that?